# Microsoft Access VB Random Generator

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel, ms-access-2007

I need to develop a model using a Monte Carlo protocol that will randomize start times between 0100 and 2300.  I am trying to create this program in Microsoft Access that will produce a randomized start time as well as a randomized activity type(Transit, Observe, Query).  The activity type should not only be random but also weighted (Transit=0.25, Observe=0.35,Query=0.40).  I am trying to write the program so that users can push a command button to produce a report with a list of at least 30 random start times and activity types (i.e. 1700 Transit, 1500 Query, etc).  I understand how to create a random number generator in Access but I am struggling in that I would like the user to be able to generate more than one start time and activity type.  So for example I want to ask the question "How many start times would you like?" and "How many activity types would you like?" in text boxes.  I would also be willing to do in Excel if I could create a user friend interface.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify how you wanted the output, but hopefully this code will get you started with the process of creating random times & weighted activities. You can determine the user interface.

```
Sub CreateRandom()
    Dim intNumTimesNeeded As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim activity As String
    Dim StartMinute As Integer
    Dim FirstTime As Integer
    Dim EndTime As Integer
    Dim StartTime As Date

    FirstTime = 1 * 60  ' first time is 1:00 am
    EndTime = 23 * 60   ' last time is 11:00 pm

    intNumTimesNeeded = 10

    For x = 1 To intNumTimesNeeded
        Randomize
        y = Rnd() * 100
        Select Case y
            Case Is >= 60
                activity = "Query"
            Case Is > 25
                activity = "Observe"
            Case Else
                activity = "Transit"
        End Select

        StartMinute = Int((EndTime - FirstTime + 1) * Rnd() + FirstTime)

        StartTime = DateAdd("n", StartMinute, "01/01/1900")

        Debug.Print Format(StartTime, "hh:mm") & " - " & activity
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel or Access ... it doesn't really matter for the application development, it's VBA in any case. The question is: what will serve the end user better: Excel or Access. I personally have never considered Access an *end user* tool per se (say without developing an applicaiton; so I clearly would prefer Excel in this case.

So strategically, you want a dialog window that

1. captures user input
2. produces one or more set of random numbers
3. presents the result to the end user

So wheter Excel or Access, steps 1, 2 are exactly the same - open the form editor, move text fields, option buttons and command buttons in (for Access don't bind it to a table), and write code for the OK button to create the output